# Getting stuck on stuck on depth_frame_id

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im running the command roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch and this is what I am getting.  I am using Ubuntu 10.10 and i have the full diamondback install...  Ive been searching for answers here but havent found anything...

Only otherthing I can think of is that I am running Ubuntu off an 8gb flashdrive

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch
... logging to /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/83abd83a-7ddf-11e1-b9e7-001b774634f0/roslaunch-ubuntu-20385.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31132/getting-stuck-on-stuck-on-depth_frame_id/) by [bub102x](https://answers.ros.org/users/2117/bub102x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-04-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That looks like perfectly normal output - you may not get any further output in the terminal if the driver is running properly.

You can verify that the driver is output point clouds by checking the `/camera/rgb/points` topic. To do that, in a separate terminal (while leaving the one the driver is running in open), you would run:

```
rostopic hz /camera/rgb/points
```

And that should output the rate at which the driver is publishing point clouds from the Kinect (likely 30Hz) (you may want to use `rostopic list` to see all of the topics the driver is publishing and select one of those - I may be slightly off on remembering what the topic that `openni_camera` publishes registered RGB data on).

If you get output from `rostopic hz`, you could view the points in rviz. To do that, follow the directions on the [Diamondback version of the openni_camera docs (Section 4)](http://ros.org/wiki/openni_camera). Make sure you are on the Diamondback documentation by selecting diamondback at the top of the documentation.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bub102x](https://answers.ros.org/users/2117/bub102x/) on 2012-04-03**:
Thanks, I will give that a try tomorrow when I have the chance to run it

**Comment by [bub102x](https://answers.ros.org/users/2117/bub102x/) on 2012-04-04**:
I tried this and i am getting out put but when I try to view the points in rviz, I do as that guide says but as soon as I turn on pointcloud2 display my CPU usages jumps to 100% and stays there and the view shows very little, nothing recognisable

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-04-04**:
That sounds like your computer might not be able to keep up with the firehose of data from the Kinect.

**Comment by [bub102x](https://answers.ros.org/users/2117/bub102x/) on 2012-04-04**:
I have an intel core 2 processor running at 2.16GHz, 2GB of ram, and a Nvidia Geforce Go 7900 GS with 256mb dedicated ram... is that not enough?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-04-04**:
How much cpu does your computer use if you just do rostopic hz /camera/rgb/points? The driver only publishes if someone is subscribed, so CPU usage with no subscribers is not a good indicator. You could also play with dynamic_reconfigure to try to get CPU usage down by using lower res images.

**Comment by [bub102x](https://answers.ros.org/users/2117/bub102x/) on 2012-04-06**:
runing just hz /camera/rgb/points my cp jumps up high around 80%... i tried on another laptop with a quadcore and all 4 jumped to around 60%. Im guessing there is something wrong with the install

or my other guess is that it is because I am running off an 8gb flash drive?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-04-23**:
The CPU usage jump is not unexpected, the node does not actually send data unless something is subscribed.  And rostopic is subscribing in a seperate process which requires serializing, sending and deserializing the point cloud stream.